# Selenium and XPath - locating a link by containing text

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use XPath to find an element containing a piece of text, but I can't get it to work....

```
WebElement searchItemByText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='popover-search']/div/div/ul/li[1]/a/span[contains(text()='Some text')]"));
```

If I remove the last bit with the "contains" thing, it locates my *span* element, but I need to select it based on the text contents. It's not going to be a perfect match of 'Some text' either, because it might contain truncated strings as well.

What is the issue?

Comment: You should show the HTML of the `a` element (and it's surrounding elements) so we can compare it's structure to what your XPath follows.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
[contains(text()='Some text')]
```

To break this down,

1. The `[]` are a conditional that operates on each individual node in
   that node set -- each span node in your case. It matches if any of the individual nodes it operates
   on match the conditions inside the brackets.
2. `text()` is a selector
   that matches all of the text nodes that are children of the context
   node -- it returns a node set.
3. `contains` is a function that operates
   on a string. If it is passed a node set, the node set is [converted
   into a string by returning the string-value of the node in the
   node-set that is first in document order](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions).

You should try to change this to

`[text()[contains(.,'Some text')]]`

1. The outer `[]` are a conditional that operates on each individual node
   in that node set `text()` is a selector that matches all of the text
   nodes that are children of the context node -- it returns a node
   set.
2. The inner `[]` are a conditional that operates on each node in that
   node set.
3. `contains` is a function that operates on a string. Here it is passed
   an individual text node (`.`).

Comment: slight change in topic, can this work for class too? ```[contains(class()='Some class')]```

Comment: We need more answers like this, not just "try this" answers.

Comment: Thx Peter, could be just me but 10 years ago it was a lot more stimulating to write better answers on this site imo

Comment: tried [text()[contains(.,'Some text')]] and it is not working...

Answer (score 14):

Use this

```
//*[@id='popover-search']/div/div/ul/li[1]/a/span[contains(text(),'Some text')]
```

OR

```
//*[@id='popover-search']/div/div/ul/li[1]/a/span[contains(.,'Some text')]
```

Comment: Thanks! Went with the first one :)

Answer (score 2):

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//button[@class='btn btn-primary' and contains(text(), 'Submit')]") private WebElementFacade submitButton;

public void clickOnSubmitButton() {
    submitButton.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me;

```
By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Your Text')]")
```

Answer (score -5):

Use:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//span[@class='y2' and contains(text(), 'Your Text')] ") 
private WebElementFacade emailLinkToVerifyAccount;
```