# Selenium : need help to locate element one class value

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```html
<div id="sessions" class="container" style="display: block;">
<div id="usrSessionList" class="list" style="height: 109px;">
<div class="alert alert-info emptyList" style="text-align: center; display: none;" data-i18n="emptySession">No existing session</div>
<div id="D37867BB-56BE-10C0-3421-904FF75AAE23" class="row tableHeight">
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 user">test12</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 opr"/>
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 lstOprId"/>
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 evt">USR_IN</div>
</div>
<div id="6E1385ED-3027-2B84-9183-433139FDE868" class="row tableHeight">
<div id="96235B5D-C8B4-5310-6E8F-B247B17482A2" class="row tableHeight">
<div id="A7BEF619-31C6-C7A9-A4C3-33B8EE583D4D" class="row tableHeight">
</div>
</div>
<div id="sessionConversation" style="display: none;">
</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to locate 'test12' by using xpath. but fail...

String expectedText = "test12";
WebElement Name= driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'"+expectedText+"')]"));

Can anyone have any other idea? 
Thanks very much!

Comment: The answer on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078308/selenium-and-xpath-locating-a-link-by-containing-text) stackoverflow question might give you a clue on how to debug this. Equally you could also use the By.className or By.cssSelector as well.

Comment: Can you please provide exception details that you are getting/

Comment: Hi everyone, 

Thanks for your help. I use this method to locate text successfully.

//div[contains(text(),'Mary')]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to write functions for things like this because it will likely be reused. For this example, it looks like you are looking for the user.

If you look in the HTML for this section

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 user">test12</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 opr" />
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 lstOprId" />
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 evt">USR_IN</div>
```

you will see that all 4 of these `DIV`s have the same classes except the last class, `user`. So with this info, we can create a CSS selector to find just this element. One way to do this is

```
public WebElement getUserName()
{
    return driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.user"));
}
```

which returns the `WebElement` that contains the user's name. You would use it like

```
System.out.println(getUserName().getText());
```

One problem with this is if there are a bunch of blocks of HTML like this one on the page listing a bunch of users. Another scenario may be that you want to find the element based on the user's name that you already know. In that case, we can find the element by contained text, the user's name. We could write a function like

```
public WebElement getUserName(String userName)
{
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'user')][.='" + userName + "']"));
}
```

and you would call it like

```
System.out.println(getUserName("test12"));
```